# Save image in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 3 application I need to give an option to the users to save a logo image for their company.

What´s the best practice and how can I implement this?

My first shot will be create a text field and save base64 image in there.

Comment: Best practice is using such gems like: [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave), [PaperClip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip), [Refile](https://github.com/refile/refile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a hoster that will give you a token in exchange of your picture, to retrieve it later. You'll then keep in your db a simple string.
Check Amazon WS, Cloudinary...

Comment: deviantsart.com is realy easy